# Rails + BMP + Capybara + Selenium webdriver + Firefox - Not able to establish connection between proxy and server while launching https site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, selenium-webdriver, capybara, browsermob-proxy

I am trying to capture the network data from a https site via browsermob proxy.

My BMP - v2.1.4, firefox - v46.0 and selenium server - v2.53.1, rails - v5.1.3.

My code is as follows,

```
require "rubygems"
require "childprocess"
require 'browsermob/proxy'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'capybara'

@proxy = BrowserMob::Proxy::Client.from("http://#{my_ip}:9090")

client_timeout = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client_timeout.timeout = 180
client = client_timeout
url = "http://#{my_ip}:4444/wd/hub"

profile     = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
proxy_sel   = @proxy.selenium_proxy(:http, :ssl)
profile['browser.cache.disk.enable']    = false
profile['browser.cache.memory.enable']  = false
profile['browser.cache.offline.enable'] = false
profile['network.http.use-cache']       = false

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(:firefox_profile => 
profile, :proxy => proxy_sel)
Capybara.register_driver :grid_firefox_proxy do |app|
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    :url => url,
    :browser => :remote,
    :http_client => client,
    :desired_capabilities => caps
)
end

Capybara.default_driver = :grid_firefox_proxy
session = Capybara::Session.new(:grid_firefox_proxy)
session.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize
@browser = session

@proxy.new_har
@browser.driver.browser.get(#{https_url})

har = @proxy.har 
puts har.entries.first.request.url
puts har.entries.first.response.status
har.save_to "mean.har"

@proxy.close
@browser.driver.quit
```

When I run this code, the browser is getting launched and it says, "Firefox cannot establish connection with the server". And in the BMP server, I am getting an error like,

```
"[ERROR 2017-10-25T13:18:17,201 org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.
ProxyToServerConnection] (LittleProxy-853-ProxyToServerWorker-2) 
(DISCONNECTED) [id: 0xecabc1af, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:63045 ! 
R:abcd.com/66.151.240.102:443]: Caught an exception 
on ProxyToServerConnection io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem"
```

When I created selenium proxy without ssl option (proxy_sel = @proxy.selenium_proxy(:http)), I am able to fetch some irrelevant network entries.

```
http://ocsp.digicert.com/
http://ocsp.digicert.com/
http://ocsp.digicert.com/
http://ss.symcd.com/
http://clients1.google.com/ocsp
http://ocsp.comodoca.com/
http://ocsp.comodoca.com/
http://ss.symcd.com/
http://clients1.google.com/ocsp
http://ocsp.digicert.com/
http://ocsp.sca1b.amazontrust.com/
http://ocsp.digicert.com/
http://clients1.google.com/ocsp
http://ocsp.digicert.com/
http://ocsp.digicert.com/
http://clients1.google.com/ocsp
http://ocsp.digicert.com/
```

I want to pull the correct network data. Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you configured the certs BMP needs to run in https mode? - https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#ssl-support

Comment: How to configure those certs? Can you send some useful links?

Comment: Any helpful links on the procedure to configure certs?